# AWS Glue JDBC Crawler - relation does not exist

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I'm using AWS Glue and have a crawler to reflect tables from a particular schema in my Redshift cluster to make those data accessible to my Glue Jobs. This crawler has been working fine for a month or more, but now all of the sudden I'm getting the following error:

```
Error crawling database reporting: SQLException: SQLState: 42P01 Error Code: 500310 Message: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: relation "{table_name}" does not exist
```

But, I can query the relevant schema & table with the exact same credentials used for the connection that Glue is using. I am able to subset to particular tables in the schema and have Glue reflect those, but not the full schema or the problematic tables it runs into.

Any ideas on how Glue reflects tables from Redshift and what might be going on here? The crawlers are all pretty black-box so I've pretty quickly run out of debugging ideas and not sure what else to try.

Comment: What does your crawler configutation look like? Êspecially the `include path`. Amazon is changing Glue interfaces every now and then, and maybe they added a parameter which makes you Crawler to fail now.

Comment: The `include_path` is just `database/schema/%`. Which worked before and has since started working again. My "fix" was basically unloading all the data, blowing away the cluster, standing up a new one, loading all the data into the new cluster and tada. Makes me wary of continuing to use glue though. Would still love to know how reflection is working and what might have been going on.